# Using sc.parallelize inside map() or any other solution?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, graphframes

I have following issue: i need to find all combinations of values in the column B per each id from the column A and return the results as DataFrame

In example below of the input DataFrame

```
        A     B       
0       5    10       
1       1    20      
2       1    15       
3       3    50       
4       5    14       
5       1    30       
6       1    15       
7       3    33
```

I need to get the following output DataFrame (it is for GraphX\GraphFrame)

```
        src dist      A
0       10   14       5
1       50   33       3
2       20   15       1
3       30   15       1
4       20   30       1
```

The one solution that I thought till now it is:

```py
df_result = df.drop_duplicates().\
               map(lambda (A,B):(A,[B])).\
               reduceByKey(lambda p, q: p + q).\
               map(lambda (A,B_values_array):(A,[k for k in itertools.combinations(B_values_array,2)]))

print df_result.take(3)
```

output: [(1, [(20,15),(30,20),(30,15)]),(5,[(10,14)]),(3,[(50,33)])]

And here I'm stuck :( how to return it to the data frame that I need? One idea was to use parallelize:

```py
import spark_sc

edges = df_result.map(lambda (A,B_pairs): spark_sc.sc.parallelize([(k[0],k[1],A) for k in B_pairs]))
```

For `spark_sc` I have other file with name spark_sc.py

```py
def init():
    global sc
    global sqlContext

    sc = SparkContext(conf=conf,
                  appName="blablabla",
                  pyFiles=['my_file_with_code.py'])

    sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
```

but my code it failed:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'sc'
```

if I use the `spark_sc.sc()` not into `map()` it works.

Any idea what I miss in the last step? is it possible at all to use `parallelize()`? or I need completely different solution?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely need another solution which could be as simple as:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import greatest, least, col

df.alias("x").join(df.alias("y"), ["A"]).select(
    least("x.B", "y.B").alias("src"), greatest("x.B", "y.B").alias("dst"), "A"
).where(col("src") != col("dst")).distinct()
```

where:

```py
df.alias("x").join(df.alias("y"), ["A"])
```

joins table with itself by `A`,

```py
least("x.B", "y.B").alias("src")
```

and

```py
greatest("x.B", "y.B")
```

choose value with a lower `id` as the source, and higher id as a destination. Finally:

```py
where(col("src") != col("dst"))
```

drops self loops.

In general it is not possible to use `SparkContext` from an action or a transformation (not that it would make any sense to do this in your case).